# Прокомментируйте работу функции bind()

Tags: javascript, функции, анонимная-функция

```js
function bind(f, context){
 return function (){
  return f.apply(context, arguments)
 };
}

function f(a){
 console.log(this);
console.log(a);
}

var a = bind(f, 'ada', 'fak');

console.log(a())
```

1) Функция `bind()` получает аргументы `f(функция)` и `context`;
2) Внутри `bind()` есть анонимная функция, где первый аргумент получает метод `apply` и становится его `context`, а 2 аргумент выводится в `console.log();` правильно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Функция `bind` вызывается с тремя аргументами: `f`, `'ada'` и '`fak'`. Переменная `a` ждёт возвращаемый функцией результат.

`var a = bind(f, 'ada', 'fak');`

- Однако обработчик функции имеет только 2 параметра: `f`(сюда после вызова попадает функция) и `context`(сюда строка `'ada'`), третий аргумент (строка `'fak'`) упускается.

`function bind(f, context)`

- Функция `bind` сразу же возвращает другую анонимную функцию, которая в свою очередь возвращает результат вызова параметра `f`. Однако вызов здесь не простой, а методом `apply`, первый параметр которого в итоге станет контекстным объектом `this` внутри вызываемой функции, а второй параметр - массив с аргументами для вызываемой функции. В данном случае вторым параметром передаётся псевдомассив `arguments`, который по умолчанию есть в каждой НЕ стрелочной функции и содержит в себе, соответственно, все переданные в функцию аргументы в виде массива. В нашем случае он будет пуст, так как переменная `a`, содержащая в себе эту анонимную функцию, в конце концов будет вызвана без аргументов (`console.log(a())`)

`return function (){
        return f.apply(context, arguments)
    };`

- Ну и сама функция `f` имеет 1 параметр `a`, который в нашем случае будет `undefined`, так как массив аргументов, при вызове через метод `apply`, был пуст.

`function f(a)`

- `console.log(this);` возвращает такой объект, так как в метод `apply` первым аргументом мы передали строку `'ada'`, которая затем неявно преобразовалась в объект.

Comment: Спасибо один момент не понятен context  в bind идет 2 аргументом;  а в  return function (){
        return f.apply(context, arguments)
    }; он становится первым  или это из -за того что первый аргумент становится функцией с методом apply ?

Comment: @xes `context` в функции `bind` - параметр, а не аргумент. Параметр - это такая переменная, которая принимает, в нашем случае, второй по счёту аргумент при вызове функции `bind` и хранит в себе его значение. Аргумент - это то, что мы передаём в функцию при её вызове. Аргументом может быть что угодно и в любом порядке.